# Fit table to textwidth AND textheight

Tags: tables, adjustbox

The table below was too long to fit the textheight and not wide enough to fit the textwidth. I would prefer the height of the table to conform to the height specified by the commented-out line '\resizebox*{!}{\dimexpr\textheight-4\baselineskip\relax}{%'. However, if I include the line, the table no longer stretches to fit the textwidth (see the line directly below). Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass [twoside,12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t!]
\centering
\caption[Reference information for the Haydn Corpus]{Reference information (Opus number, work, movement, measures), keys, time signatures, and tempo markings for the exposition sections of each movement in the Haydn Corpus.}
%\resizebox*{!}{\dimexpr\textheight-4\baselineskip\relax}{%
\begin{tabular*}{1.0\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} lccl}
\toprule
\textit{Excerpts} & \textit{Key} & \textit{Time Signature} & \textit{Tempo Marking} \\
\midrule
Op. 17, No. 1, i, mm. 1–43  & E     & 4/4   & Moderato \\
Op. 17, No. 2, i, mm. 1–38  & F     & 4/4   & Moderato \\
Op. 17, No. 3, iv, mm. 1–26 & Eb    & 4/4   & Allegro molto \\
Op. 17, No. 4, i, mm. 1–53 & c     & 4/4   & Moderato \\
Op. 17, No. 5, i, mm. 1–33  & G     & 4/4   & Moderato \\
Op. 17, No. 6, i, mm. 1–73  & D     & 6/8   & Presto \\
Op. 20, No. 1, iv, mm. 1–55 & Eb    & 2/4   & Presto \\
Op. 20, No. 3, i, mm. 1–94  & g     & 2/4   & Allegro con spirito \\
Op. 20, No. 3, iii, mm. 1–43  & G     & 3/4   & Poco Adagio \\
Op. 20, No. 3, iv, mm. 1–42  & g     & 4/4   & Allegro molto \\
Op. 20, No. 4, i, mm. 1–112  & D     & 3/4   & Allegro di molto \\
Op. 20, No. 4, iv, mm. 1–49   & D     & 4/4   & Presto scherzando \\
Op. 20, No. 5, i, mm. 1–48  & f     & 4/4   & Allegro moderato \\
Op. 20, No. 6, ii, mm. 1–27  & E     & cut   & Adagio \\
Op. 33, No. 1, i, mm. 1–37  & b     & 4/4   & Allegro moderato \\
Op. 33, No. 1, iii, mm. 1–40  & D     & 6/8   & Andante \\
Op. 33, No. 2, i, mm. 1–32  & Eb    & 4/4   & Allegro moderato \\
Op. 33, No. 3, iii, mm. 1–29  & F     & 3/4   & Adagio \\
Op. 33, No. 4, i, mm. 1–31  & Bb    & 4/4   & Allegro moderato \\
Op. 33, No. 5, i, mm. 1–95   & G     & 2/4   & Vivace assai \\
Op. 33, No. 5, ii, mm. 1–30  & g     & 4/4   & Largo \\
Op. 50, No. 1, i, mm. 1–60  & Bb    & cut   & Allegro \\
Op. 50, No. 1, iv, mm. 1–75  & Bb    & 2/4   & Vivace \\
Op. 50, No. 2, i, mm. 1–106  & C     & 3/4   & Vivace \\
Op. 50, No. 2, iv, mm. 1–86   & C     & 2/4   & Vivace assai \\
Op. 50, No. 3, iv, mm. 1–74  & Eb    & 2/4   & Presto \\
Op. 50, No. 4, i, mm. 1–64  & f\#   & 3/4   & Allegro spirituoso \\
Op. 50, No. 5, i, mm. 1–65  & F     & 2/4   & Allegro moderato \\
Op. 50, No. 5, iv, mm. 1–54  & F     & 6/8   & Vivace \\
Op. 50, No. 6, i, mm. 1–54  & D     & 4/4   & Allegro \\
Op. 50, No. 6, ii, mm. 1–25  & d     & 6/8   & Poco Adagio \\
Op. 54, No. 1, i, mm. 1–47  & G     & 4/4   & Allegro con brio \\
Op. 54, No. 1, ii, mm. 1–54  & C     & 6/8   & Allegretto \\
Op. 54, No. 2, i, mm. 1–87  & C     & 4/4   & Vivace \\
Op. 54, No. 3, i, mm. 1–58  & E     & cut   & Allegro \\
Op. 54, No. 3, iv, mm. 1–82  & E     & 2/4   & Presto \\
Op. 55, No. 1, ii, mm. 1–36  & D     & 2/4   & Adagio cantabile \\
Op. 55, No. 2, ii, mm. 1–76  & f     & cut   & Allegro \\
Op. 55, No. 3, i, mm. 1–75  & Bb    & 3/4   & Vivace assai \\
Op. 64, No. 3, i, mm. 1–69  & Bb    & 3/4   & Vivace assai \\
Op. 64, No. 3, iv, mm. 1–79  & Bb    & 2/4   & Allegro con spirito \\
Op. 64, No. 4, i, mm. 1–38   & G     & 4/4   & Allegro con brio \\
Op. 64, No. 4, iv, mm. 1–66  & G     & 6/8   & Presto \\
Op. 64, No. 6, i, mm. 1–45  & Eb    & 4/4   & Allegretto \\
Op. 71, No. 1, i, mm. 1–69  & Bb    & 4/4   & Allegro \\
Op. 74, No. 1, i, mm. 1–54  & C     & 4/4   & Allegro moderato \\
Op. 74, No. 1, ii, mm. 1–57  & G     & 3/8   & Andantino grazioso \\
Op. 76, No. 2, i, mm. 1–56  & d     & 4/4   & Allegro \\
Op. 76, No. 4, i, mm. 1–68  & Bb    & 4/4   & Allegro con spirito \\
Op. 76, No. 5, ii, mm. 1–33  & F\#   & cut   & Largo. Cantabile e mesto \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}%}
\label{tab:haydncorpus} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please fix the example to be a complete document that shows the problem and allows answers to be tested, at the very least it would show the required page size. In general though scaling tables should be a non-aim, just as paragraphs are not artificially distorted to make them fit a specified size.

Comment: I suppose you could use the command `\resizebox*{\textwidth}{\dimexpr\textheight-4\baselineskip\relax}{...}`. However, the result would be simply awful, aesthetically speaking. Have you considered using a `longtable` environment and letting the tabular material occupy about 1-1/2 pages?

Comment: @David Carlisle As requested, I revised the document. I'm aware of using footnotesize, but then the table is too short to fill the page, and latex puts text below the table on the same page instead of skipping to the top of the next page. I'd prefer to retain the textwidth, but find a way to make the table conform to the textheight.

Comment: @Mico, as you point out, the solution you offered looks awful, and I'd prefer not to use longtable, which stretches the table across two pages (my advisor hated how it looked).

Comment: I don't understand your comment that `\footnotesize` is too small, in the version I posted it more or less exactly filed the page, you have since edited to show you are using 12pt, which makes `\footnotesize` too large, and you need `\tiny`.

Answer (score 3):

Scaling text leads to arbitrary font sizes and it's better to use class specified fonts such as `\footnotesize` which, depending on the font family in use may 
also be using the font design for that size, rather than a simple scaled version.

If it needs to be on one page, something like this, although a multi-page table may be better.

Personally I'd just use `tabular` not force it to be full width with `tabular*`, spreading the columns just makes it harder to read across the table rows, but I have used `tabular*` here (correcting your preamble which was missing `@{}`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[tp]
\centering
\caption[Reference information for the Haydn Corpus]{Reference information (Opus number, work, movement, measures), keys, time signatures, and tempo markings for the exposition sections of each movement in the Haydn Corpus.}

\footnotesize
\begin{tabular*}{1.0\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} lccl@{}}
\toprule
\textit{Excerpts} & \textit{Key} & \textit{Time Signature} & \textit{Tempo Marking} \\
\midrule
Op. 17, No. 1, i, mm. 1–43  & E     & 4/4   & Moderato \\
Op. 17, No. 2, i, mm. 1–38  & F     & 4/4   & Moderato \\
Op. 17, No. 3, iv, mm. 1–26 & Eb    & 4/4   & Allegro molto \\
Op. 17, No. 4, i, mm. 1–53 & c     & 4/4   & Moderato \\
Op. 17, No. 5, i, mm. 1–33  & G     & 4/4   & Moderato \\
Op. 17, No. 6, i, mm. 1–73  & D     & 6/8   & Presto \\
Op. 20, No. 1, iv, mm. 1–55 & Eb    & 2/4   & Presto \\
Op. 20, No. 3, i, mm. 1–94  & g     & 2/4   & Allegro con spirito \\
Op. 20, No. 3, iii, mm. 1–43  & G     & 3/4   & Poco Adagio \\
Op. 20, No. 3, iv, mm. 1–42  & g     & 4/4   & Allegro molto \\
Op. 20, No. 4, i, mm. 1–112  & D     & 3/4   & Allegro di molto \\
Op. 20, No. 4, iv, mm. 1–49   & D     & 4/4   & Presto scherzando \\
Op. 20, No. 5, i, mm. 1–48  & f     & 4/4   & Allegro moderato \\
Op. 20, No. 6, ii, mm. 1–27  & E     & cut   & Adagio \\
Op. 33, No. 1, i, mm. 1–37  & b     & 4/4   & Allegro moderato \\
Op. 33, No. 1, iii, mm. 1–40  & D     & 6/8   & Andante \\
Op. 33, No. 2, i, mm. 1–32  & Eb    & 4/4   & Allegro moderato \\
Op. 33, No. 3, iii, mm. 1–29  & F     & 3/4   & Adagio \\
Op. 33, No. 4, i, mm. 1–31  & Bb    & 4/4   & Allegro moderato \\
Op. 33, No. 5, i, mm. 1–95   & G     & 2/4   & Vivace assai \\
Op. 33, No. 5, ii, mm. 1–30  & g     & 4/4   & Largo \\
Op. 50, No. 1, i, mm. 1–60  & Bb    & cut   & Allegro \\
Op. 50, No. 1, iv, mm. 1–75  & Bb    & 2/4   & Vivace \\
Op. 50, No. 2, i, mm. 1–106  & C     & 3/4   & Vivace \\
Op. 50, No. 2, iv, mm. 1–86   & C     & 2/4   & Vivace assai \\
Op. 50, No. 3, iv, mm. 1–74  & Eb    & 2/4   & Presto \\
Op. 50, No. 4, i, mm. 1–64  & f\#   & 3/4   & Allegro spirituoso \\
Op. 50, No. 5, i, mm. 1–65  & F     & 2/4   & Allegro moderato \\
Op. 50, No. 5, iv, mm. 1–54  & F     & 6/8   & Vivace \\
Op. 50, No. 6, i, mm. 1–54  & D     & 4/4   & Allegro \\
Op. 50, No. 6, ii, mm. 1–25  & d     & 6/8   & Poco Adagio \\
Op. 54, No. 1, i, mm. 1–47  & G     & 4/4   & Allegro con brio \\
Op. 54, No. 1, ii, mm. 1–54  & C     & 6/8   & Allegretto \\
Op. 54, No. 2, i, mm. 1–87  & C     & 4/4   & Vivace \\
Op. 54, No. 3, i, mm. 1–58  & E     & cut   & Allegro \\
Op. 54, No. 3, iv, mm. 1–82  & E     & 2/4   & Presto \\
Op. 55, No. 1, ii, mm. 1–36  & D     & 2/4   & Adagio cantabile \\
Op. 55, No. 2, ii, mm. 1–76  & f     & cut   & Allegro \\
Op. 55, No. 3, i, mm. 1–75  & Bb    & 3/4   & Vivace assai \\
Op. 64, No. 3, i, mm. 1–69  & Bb    & 3/4   & Vivace assai \\
Op. 64, No. 3, iv, mm. 1–79  & Bb    & 2/4   & Allegro con spirito \\
Op. 64, No. 4, i, mm. 1–38   & G     & 4/4   & Allegro con brio \\
Op. 64, No. 4, iv, mm. 1–66  & G     & 6/8   & Presto \\
Op. 64, No. 6, i, mm. 1–45  & Eb    & 4/4   & Allegretto \\
Op. 71, No. 1, i, mm. 1–69  & Bb    & 4/4   & Allegro \\
Op. 74, No. 1, i, mm. 1–54  & C     & 4/4   & Allegro moderato \\
Op. 74, No. 1, ii, mm. 1–57  & G     & 3/8   & Andantino grazioso \\
Op. 76, No. 2, i, mm. 1–56  & d     & 4/4   & Allegro \\
Op. 76, No. 4, i, mm. 1–68  & Bb    & 4/4   & Allegro con spirito \\
Op. 76, No. 5, ii, mm. 1–33  & F\#   & cut   & Largo. Cantabile e mesto \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\label{tab:haydncorpus} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

question has been edited to show `12pt` option is in force, in which case more drastic action is required to make it fit in one page:

[image]

```
\documentclass [twoside,12pt,letterpaper]{report}
%LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page by 129.1507pt on input line 68.

\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[tp]
\centering
\vspace{-55pt}
\small
\caption[Reference information for the Haydn Corpus]{Reference information (Opus number, work, movement, measures), keys, time signatures, and tempo markings for the exposition sections of each movement in the Haydn Corpus.}

\footnotesize\renewcommand\arraystretch{.9}
\begin{tabular*}{1.0\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} lccl@{}}
\toprule
\textit{Excerpts} & \textit{Key} & \textit{Time Signature} & \textit{Tempo Marking} \\
\midrule
Op. 17, No. 1, i, mm. 1–43  & E     & 4/4   & Moderato \\
Op. 17, No. 2, i, mm. 1–38  & F     & 4/4   & Moderato \\
Op. 17, No. 3, iv, mm. 1–26 & Eb    & 4/4   & Allegro molto \\
Op. 17, No. 4, i, mm. 1–53 & c     & 4/4   & Moderato \\
Op. 17, No. 5, i, mm. 1–33  & G     & 4/4   & Moderato \\
Op. 17, No. 6, i, mm. 1–73  & D     & 6/8   & Presto \\
Op. 20, No. 1, iv, mm. 1–55 & Eb    & 2/4   & Presto \\
Op. 20, No. 3, i, mm. 1–94  & g     & 2/4   & Allegro con spirito \\
Op. 20, No. 3, iii, mm. 1–43  & G     & 3/4   & Poco Adagio \\
Op. 20, No. 3, iv, mm. 1–42  & g     & 4/4   & Allegro molto \\
Op. 20, No. 4, i, mm. 1–112  & D     & 3/4   & Allegro di molto \\
Op. 20, No. 4, iv, mm. 1–49   & D     & 4/4   & Presto scherzando \\
Op. 20, No. 5, i, mm. 1–48  & f     & 4/4   & Allegro moderato \\
Op. 20, No. 6, ii, mm. 1–27  & E     & cut   & Adagio \\
Op. 33, No. 1, i, mm. 1–37  & b     & 4/4   & Allegro moderato \\
Op. 33, No. 1, iii, mm. 1–40  & D     & 6/8   & Andante \\
Op. 33, No. 2, i, mm. 1–32  & Eb    & 4/4   & Allegro moderato \\
Op. 33, No. 3, iii, mm. 1–29  & F     & 3/4   & Adagio \\
Op. 33, No. 4, i, mm. 1–31  & Bb    & 4/4   & Allegro moderato \\
Op. 33, No. 5, i, mm. 1–95   & G     & 2/4   & Vivace assai \\
Op. 33, No. 5, ii, mm. 1–30  & g     & 4/4   & Largo \\
Op. 50, No. 1, i, mm. 1–60  & Bb    & cut   & Allegro \\
Op. 50, No. 1, iv, mm. 1–75  & Bb    & 2/4   & Vivace \\
Op. 50, No. 2, i, mm. 1–106  & C     & 3/4   & Vivace \\
Op. 50, No. 2, iv, mm. 1–86   & C     & 2/4   & Vivace assai \\
Op. 50, No. 3, iv, mm. 1–74  & Eb    & 2/4   & Presto \\
Op. 50, No. 4, i, mm. 1–64  & f\#   & 3/4   & Allegro spirituoso \\
Op. 50, No. 5, i, mm. 1–65  & F     & 2/4   & Allegro moderato \\
Op. 50, No. 5, iv, mm. 1–54  & F     & 6/8   & Vivace \\
Op. 50, No. 6, i, mm. 1–54  & D     & 4/4   & Allegro \\
Op. 50, No. 6, ii, mm. 1–25  & d     & 6/8   & Poco Adagio \\
Op. 54, No. 1, i, mm. 1–47  & G     & 4/4   & Allegro con brio \\
Op. 54, No. 1, ii, mm. 1–54  & C     & 6/8   & Allegretto \\
Op. 54, No. 2, i, mm. 1–87  & C     & 4/4   & Vivace \\
Op. 54, No. 3, i, mm. 1–58  & E     & cut   & Allegro \\
Op. 54, No. 3, iv, mm. 1–82  & E     & 2/4   & Presto \\
Op. 55, No. 1, ii, mm. 1–36  & D     & 2/4   & Adagio cantabile \\
Op. 55, No. 2, ii, mm. 1–76  & f     & cut   & Allegro \\
Op. 55, No. 3, i, mm. 1–75  & Bb    & 3/4   & Vivace assai \\
Op. 64, No. 3, i, mm. 1–69  & Bb    & 3/4   & Vivace assai \\
Op. 64, No. 3, iv, mm. 1–79  & Bb    & 2/4   & Allegro con spirito \\
Op. 64, No. 4, i, mm. 1–38   & G     & 4/4   & Allegro con brio \\
Op. 64, No. 4, iv, mm. 1–66  & G     & 6/8   & Presto \\
Op. 64, No. 6, i, mm. 1–45  & Eb    & 4/4   & Allegretto \\
Op. 71, No. 1, i, mm. 1–69  & Bb    & 4/4   & Allegro \\
Op. 74, No. 1, i, mm. 1–54  & C     & 4/4   & Allegro moderato \\
Op. 74, No. 1, ii, mm. 1–57  & G     & 3/8   & Andantino grazioso \\
Op. 76, No. 2, i, mm. 1–56  & d     & 4/4   & Allegro \\
Op. 76, No. 4, i, mm. 1–68  & Bb    & 4/4   & Allegro con spirito \\
Op. 76, No. 5, ii, mm. 1–33  & F\#   & cut   & Largo. Cantabile e mesto \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\label{tab:haydncorpus} 
\vspace{-20pt}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but as I commented above, I'd prefer to scale the table so that it fills the page. Any suggestions?

Comment: @DavidS answer updated with `[12pt]` to match new question.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to suggest that you use a `longtable` environment and let the table occupy more than one page. To me, such a solution is preferable to one that reduces the font size used for the table. The code below shows how one may set up a `longtable` so that its width equals that of the text block.

Aside: The table contains a lot of abbreviations of the form `Op.`, `No.`, and `mm.`. To inform TeX that the periods (full stops) in these terms are not of the sentence-ending variety, you could replace all space characters that immediately follow the dots with `~`.

The first few lines of the resulting table will look like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable}
\begin{document}
%%\listoftables

\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\textwidth}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lcl@{}}
\caption[Reference information for the Haydn Corpus]{Reference information (Opus number, work, movement, measures), keys, time signatures, and tempo markings for the exposition sections of each movement in the Haydn Corpus.} \label{tab:haydncorpus} \\
\toprule
\textit{Excerpts} & \textit{Key} & \textit{Time} & \textit{Tempo Marking} \\
& & \textit{Signature}\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption*{Table \ref{tab:haydncorpus}, continued}\\
\toprule
\textit{Excerpts} & \textit{Key} & \textit{Time} & \textit{Tempo Marking} \\
& & \textit{Signature}\\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{r@{}}{continued \dots}\\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
Op.~17, No.~1, i, mm.~1–43  & E     & 4/4   & Moderato \\
Op.~17, No.~2, i, mm.~1–38  & F     & 4/4   & Moderato \\
Op.~17, No.~3, iv, mm.~1–26 & E$\flat$    & 4/4   & Allegro molto \\
Op.~17, No.~4, i, mm.~1–53 & c     & 4/4   & Moderato \\
Op.~17, No.~5, i, mm.~1–33  & G     & 4/4   & Moderato \\
Op.~17, No.~6, i, mm.~1–73  & D     & 6/8   & Presto \\
Op.~20, No.~1, iv, mm.~1–55 & E$\flat$    & 2/4   & Presto \\
Op.~20, No.~3, i, mm.~1–94  & g     & 2/4   & Allegro con spirito \\
Op.~20, No.~3, iii, mm.~1–43  & G     & 3/4   & Poco Adagio \\
Op.~20, No.~3, iv, mm.~1–42  & g     & 4/4   & Allegro molto \\
Op.~20, No.~4, i, mm.~1–112  & D     & 3/4   & Allegro di molto \\
Op.~20, No.~4, iv, mm.~1–49   & D     & 4/4   & Presto scherzando \\
Op.~20, No.~5, i, mm.~1–48  & f     & 4/4   & Allegro moderato \\
Op.~20, No.~6, ii, mm.~1–27  & E     & cut   & Adagio \\
Op.~33, No.~1, i, mm.~1–37  & b     & 4/4   & Allegro moderato \\
Op.~33, No.~1, iii, mm.~1–40  & D     & 6/8   & Andante \\
Op.~33, No.~2, i, mm.~1–32  & E$\flat$    & 4/4   & Allegro moderato \\
Op.~33, No.~3, iii, mm.~1–29  & F     & 3/4   & Adagio \\
Op.~33, No.~4, i, mm.~1–31  & B$\flat$    & 4/4   & Allegro moderato \\
Op.~33, No.~5, i, mm.~1–95   & G     & 2/4   & Vivace assai \\
Op.~33, No.~5, ii, mm.~1–30  & g     & 4/4   & Largo \\
Op.~50, No.~1, i, mm.~1–60  & B$\flat$    & cut   & Allegro \\
Op.~50, No.~1, iv, mm.~1–75  & B$\flat$    & 2/4   & Vivace \\
Op.~50, No.~2, i, mm.~1–106  & C     & 3/4   & Vivace \\
Op.~50, No.~2, iv, mm.~1–86   & C     & 2/4   & Vivace assai \\
Op.~50, No.~3, iv, mm.~1–74  & E$\flat$    & 2/4   & Presto \\
Op.~50, No.~4, i, mm.~1–64  & f$\sharp$   & 3/4   & Allegro spirituoso \\
Op.~50, No.~5, i, mm.~1–65  & F     & 2/4   & Allegro moderato \\
Op.~50, No.~5, iv, mm.~1–54  & F     & 6/8   & Vivace \\
Op.~50, No.~6, i, mm.~1–54  & D     & 4/4   & Allegro \\
Op.~50, No.~6, ii, mm.~1–25  & d     & 6/8   & Poco Adagio \\
Op.~54, No.~1, i, mm.~1–47  & G     & 4/4   & Allegro con brio \\
Op.~54, No.~1, ii, mm.~1–54  & C     & 6/8   & Allegretto \\
Op.~54, No.~2, i, mm.~1–87  & C     & 4/4   & Vivace \\
Op.~54, No.~3, i, mm.~1–58  & E     & cut   & Allegro \\
Op.~54, No.~3, iv, mm.~1–82  & E     & 2/4   & Presto \\
Op.~55, No.~1, ii, mm.~1–36  & D     & 2/4   & Adagio cantabile \\
Op.~55, No.~2, ii, mm.~1–76  & f     & cut   & Allegro \\
Op.~55, No.~3, i, mm.~1–75  & B$\flat$    & 3/4   & Vivace assai \\
Op.~64, No.~3, i, mm.~1–69  & B$\flat$    & 3/4   & Vivace assai \\
Op.~64, No.~3, iv, mm.~1–79  & B$\flat$    & 2/4   & Allegro con spirito \\
Op.~64, No.~4, i, mm.~1–38   & G     & 4/4   & Allegro con brio \\
Op.~64, No.~4, iv, mm.~1–66  & G     & 6/8   & Presto \\
Op.~64, No.~6, i, mm.~1–45  & E$\flat$    & 4/4   & Allegretto \\
Op.~71, No.~1, i, mm.~1–69  & B$\flat$    & 4/4   & Allegro \\
Op.~74, No.~1, i, mm.~1–54  & C     & 4/4   & Allegro moderato \\
Op.~74, No.~1, ii, mm.~1–57  & G     & 3/8   & Andantino grazioso \\
Op.~76, No.~2, i, mm.~1–56  & d     & 4/4   & Allegro \\
Op.~76, No.~4, i, mm.~1–68  & B$\flat$    & 4/4   & Allegro con spirito \\
Op.~76, No.~5, ii, mm.~1–33  & F$\sharp$   & cut   & Largo. Cantabile e mesto \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the longtable option. If I can't find a better solution, I might try it. Just to confirm, does adding the tildes decrease the space between the full stops and the next character?

Comment: @DavidS - That's correct: Using tildes makes the space after the dots act like an ordinary interword space rather than like the (larger) space after a sentence-ending full stop. The fact that the space generated by the tildes is unbreakable is secondary in this context.

Comment: @DavidS - What are the actual text block dimensions of your document?